# form_for tag parameters in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

Basically I understand associations clearly but in that one thing not clear to me.

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

In that what is 2nd parameter and its purpose. Is 2nd parameter for action_url or not?

Comment: check here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Comment: Check the documentation about [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @post]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

is to generate path like admin_post_url_path.

If you want to specify an url, use:

```
<%= form_for(your_record, url: your_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is used for nested resources, if you have `/articles/:article_id/comments/new`, the array syntax `[@article, @article.comments.build]` is to create a new comment as a nested resource for given article

Comment: But after that it go to comments controller then why it go it no go in article controller?

Comment: Nested resources are only a matter of routing, the controller where you end up posting the Comment **must be CommentsController**, so what's happening is correct. That form is used to build new comments, not new articles

Comment: No, basically `form_for([@article, @article.comments.build])` uses only `@article.id` to fill in the route, nothing else